# Computing Relative Information Loss [reopened]

Tags: information-theory

I have a function that outputs a value of $y = 6$ at some datapoint. Now I decrease the dimension of that function and the updated function outputs say, $y = 5.7$. How do I compute information loss as a result of this change in dimensionality reduction? Assuming that the first function has higher dimension and second function has lower, how do I quantify such "relative" information loss by using the outputs from the two functions?

Comment: Reposting a question does not reopen it: it just irritates people who have to consolidate or link the two threads.  Please read our [help] for more about how this site works.

Comment: @whuber why was the question closed without giving specific reasoning?

Comment: The reason was given: "This question needs details or clarity."

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy could you please specify what additional details are needed? For me the question is very much too the point.

Comment: "Model" and "relative information loss" are so vague that both need elaboration.

Comment: ok i will clarify this point and hope the question is openend.

Comment: It's still impossible to determine what you're doing.  What is the "dimension" of a function?  What is "relative information loss"?  Why would there be any prospect of even answering a question like this based on a single input-output pair?

Comment: @whuber allright thanks for clarifying. I will update the question. Also to answer ```Why would there be any prospect of even answering a question like this based on a single input-output pair?```. I am looking for the information loss at a single data point. so from 6 to 5.7 we know we lost some information. How can we quantify such loss for a single datapoint.

Comment: Information loss has to be relative to some distribution.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Isnt information loss here is relative to "uncertainty increase" of prediction output if we reduce the dimensionality of the function, hence decrease its accuracy in prediction?

Comment: Uncertainty is also defined in terms of a distribution. You’ve mentioned nothing about accuracy so far, because you haven’t provided a ground truth. It’s not clear that accuracy is relevant here. You’ve given two specific model outputs (for the same input). If you want to define information loss, you need to do so according to a distribution. This is true of basically every quantity in information theory. Take some time to think this through, then edit those details into your question. If there are parts of this that confuse you, they should be posted as new, self-contained questions.

Comment: This paper may help you to organize your thoughts: https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0429

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy thanks for the help!